# Error compiling interceptions

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

My app isn't compiling when attempting use interceptions such as...

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;

public class Secure extends Controller {

    @Before
    static void checkAuthenticated(){
      ...
    }

    ...

}
```

The exception is "error: cannot find symbol @Before".  I've tried cleaning, rebuilding Eclipse project from console and reordering Java Build Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All @Before, @After, @Catch, @Finally have been merged into a single
>   simpler concept:
>
> http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition

To learn more, checkout zentasks example inside your play installation (samples) folder, it implements `Security.Authenticator`